# How to subscribe to system changes on MacOS?

Tags: macos

I'm helping someone write an Emacs plugin to have Emacs automatically change its theme whenever the system color scheme changes.

Currently the way it works is by polling the system for its color scheme. We would prefer it to instead subscribe to updates, similar to how DBus on Linux allows you to do pubsub with its signals.

Is there some way on MacOS to subscribe instead of poll?

Comment: Can you show some code of how you are retrieving the system’s color scheme?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this plug-in is running an AppKit context — that is, the main app into which it's plugging is based on AppKit — then you can key-value observe the `effectiveAppearance` of the `NSApplication` object:

```
[NSApp addObserver:self
        forKeyPath:@"effectiveAppearance"
           options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial
           context:someValueUniqueToYourClass];
```

You'll need to implement `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` in your class to receive the change notification.

When it changes, you can call:

```
NSAppearanceName* match = [NSApp.effectiveAppearance bestMatchFromAppearancesWithNames:
                               @[NSAppearanceNameAqua, NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua]];
if ([match isEqual:NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua])
     // switch Emacs to dark mode
else
     // switch Emacs to light mode
```